# Covariance using formula is not the same as "actual" covariance?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I have a matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ (as you will see below) and I am trying to compute its covariance. However, explicitly using the covariance formula (note that $\mathbf{C}$ is centered so the meanY disappears from the formula) gives another result than when using the CovarianceMatrix command from Maple as illustrated here
[image]

Any idea why? I am using the covariance for an assignment and want to be sure that it is correct. I am showing the steps to compute the covariance matrix so cannot just refer to the formula and jump to the result than Maple (and numpy) gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be dividing by $n-1 = 7$, not by $n=8$.